# remove black background in constant line in lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

when I add constant line its adding some black background behind the line , this is happening in line series too , how do i disable this effect only on constantline

```
axis.addConstantLine(false).setMouseInteractions(false);
```

[image]

Also constantline seems to be very slow when i add 100's of it , v3 was much faster.Can I know why.

Answer (score 0):

This background comes from a [glow effect](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.1.1/classes/GlowEffect.html) that is enabled by default on the default themes.

You can disable this effect for the constantline with [`constantLine.setEffect(false)`](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.1.1/classes/ConstantLine.html#setEffect). Similar API to control the effect state can be found on all other elements that support effects as well.

There also is a [`disableThemeEffects`](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.1.1/functions/disableThemeEffects.html) function to disable all of the effects for a theme.

```js
 const chart = lc.ChartXY({
     theme: disableThemeEffects(Themes.cyberSpace)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks , i tried it removes the effect , but it slows down the chart drastically if i scroll the charts or drag the charts if there are 100's of constant lines.